# WPF Converter with Property in Static Resource

Tags: wpf, converters, staticresource

I have a converter which has a property VisibleLength

```
public class BoolToGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value == true) ? new GridLength(0) : new GridLength(VisibleLength);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public double VisibleLength { get; set; }
}
```

In App.xaml I have defined the resource as

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ns:BoolToGridLengthConverter
        x:Key="boolToGridLengthConverter"
     />
</Application.Resources>
```

and using in xaml as

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=boolProperty, Converter={StaticResource boolToGridLengthConverter}}" />
```

How can I use the Property to pass VisibleLenght property=doubleValue to converter from xaml.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `VisibleLength` to be the same for all usages of the converter, then just do

```
<ns:BoolToGridLengthConverter x:Key="..." VisibleLength="40"/>
```

However, it sounds a bit like you want to make this decision at the usage site. In that case, you can drop the property from the converter class and instead use the parameter:

```
<RowDefinition
    Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource boolToGridLengthConverter}, ConverterParameter=40, Path=boolProperty}"
/>
```

and your implementation changes as follows:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (bool)value ? new GridLength(0) : new GridLength(Convert.ToDouble(parameter));
}
```

Comment: But what if I wanted to use the property?

Answer (score 2):

You may not even need a Binding Converter at all.

Just use a DataTrigger in a RowDefinition Style:

```
<RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding boolProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RowDefinition.Style>
</RowDefinition>
```

Optionally, declare the Style as resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RowDefStyle" TargetType="RowDefinition">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding boolProperty}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

...
<RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource RowDefStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Generally a DataTrigger should be a bit lighter than a Converter, right? At least I've noticed that the default WPF styles do a lot with triggers that a naïve younger me would probably have used converters for.

Comment: IMO the advantage is that you only have XAML declarations without any additional code in a converter class. It's clearer to see how it behaves.